# Need to send All Folders Names that apply forfiles condition to Excel file

Tags: excel, batch-file

My forfiles command is:

```
forfiles /p "%%~a" /d %days% /c "cmd /c if /i @isdir==true echo Deleting... @path & rd /s /q @path"
```

If I write:

```
echo @path>>Folders_that_deleted.xls
```

Inside the `'Forfiles'` command It will produce Excel file in every subfolder
that apply the condition! And what I need is to send all Folders names prior delete to **ONE** excel file.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can include the full path to where the file should be

```
echo @path>>d:\somewhere\Folders_that_deleted.xls
```

Or, better, redirect the full `forfiles`

```
>> folders_that_deleted.xls ( 
    forfiles /p "%%~a" /d %days% /c "cmd /c if /i @isdir==true echo Deleting... @path & rd /s /q @path" 
)
```

Comment: Actually I tried the first answer and I got "Access is denied". And the othere answer It doesn't help because 'forfiles' command is inside 'for' loop and I will get many excel files in deferent locations. @MC ND

Comment: @YWATFA, silly question but, have you changed the path in the first case? you need to adapt it to you environment. For the second case, unless you are changing the current active folder (`cd` or `pushd`), there is no difference if the code is or not inside a `for` loop. And, in the case you are changing the current active folder, include the full path to where you want the xls file created.

Comment: Sure I changed the path. I changed the path to another location and it works now!